# Elasticsearch 2: Can I filter terms aggregation by keys

Tags: elasticsearch, search-engine

Is it possible to filter the terms aggregation by key? I did a terms aggregation on an array field, which resulted a lot of unnecessary buckets. (Even though I applied a filter to the query)

For example for a result like this:

```
{
"took" : 3,
"timed_out" : false,
"_shards" : {
    "total" : 5,
    "successful" : 5,
    "failed" : 0
},
"hits" : {
    "total" : 9928,
    "max_score" : 0.0,
    "hits" : [ ]
},
"aggregations" : {
    "variables" : {
        "buckets" : [ {
            "key" : "00",
            "doc_count" : 158
        }, {
            "key" : "1",
            "doc_count" : 158
        }, {
            "key" : "2",
            "doc_count" : 158
        }, {
            "key" : "3",
            "doc_count" : 158
        }, {
            "key" : "4",
            "doc_count" : 158
        }, {
            "key" : "5",
            "doc_count" : 158
        }, {
            "key" : "6",
                "doc_count" : 156
        }, {
            "key" : "7",
                "doc_count" : 127
        }, {
            "key" : "8",
                "doc_count" : 121
        }, {
            "key" : "9",
                "doc_count" : 104
        } ]
    }
}
}
```

What I want to do is to tell ElasticSearch to only keep buckets where key=[1,2,3,4,5].

Update:

Here is the query I used:

```
POST xxtransaction/_search?ignore_unavailable=true
{
  "size" : 0,
  "timeout" : 30000,
  "terminate_after" : 10000000,
  "query" : {
    "filtered" : {
      "filter" : {
        "and" : {
          "filters" : [ {
            "range" : {
              "transaction_time" : {
                "from" : 1459461600000,
                "to" : 1459547999999,
                "include_lower" : true,
                "include_upper" : true
              }
            }
          }, {
            "term" : {
              "site" : "xxx.com"
            }
          }, {
            "terms" : {
              "category_codes" : [ 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]
            }
          } ]
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "aggregations" : {
    "category_codes" : {
      "terms" : {
        "field" : "category_codes",
        "size" : 20000
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Give us your original query

Comment: Please provide a sample document as well.